# '.class' error cannot be identified?

Tags: java

I am making a hangman game, this is the part of my code where all the problems are:

```
    //play method
    private void play() throws IOException
    {
        guess(alphabet);

        usedLetters(letterUsed);

        do{
            centreln("You have already guessed this " + alphabet + " and the others listed above.");
            guess();
        } while (letterUsed == true);//will keep asking until letter was not used

        if (letterUsed == false)
        {
            life--;
            underWord();
        } //only if the letter was not used, it will be checked for in the current word trying to be solved

        if (life == 0)
        {
            checkWord(currentWord[] , checkLetter[]);
        }
    }//End of play method
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//maskWord method to return the word with all characters not in letters replaced by _'s
private void underWord(char currentWord[] , char checkLetter[]) throws IOException //add parameters what it recieves
{

    for (int i = 0; i<currentWord.length; i++) {
       for (int index = 0; index<checkLetter.length; index++){
            if (used.contains(currentWord.charAt(i)))
            {
                checkLetter[index] =  currentWord.charAt(i);
            }

            else
            {
                checkLetter[index] = '_';
            }
       }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < checkLetter.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(checkLetter[i]);
    }
}//End of maskWord method
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//guess method to ask for user's guess
private void guess(char used[]) throws IOException//add parameters what it recieves
{
    centreln("Guess a letter in this 5-letter word: ");
    alphabet = kb.readline().charAt[0];
    used[dataSize] = alphabet;
    //adds guess to used letters array

}//End of guess method
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//usedLetters method to check if user's guess has already been guessed
private boolean usedLetters(char used[]) throws IOException//add parameters what it recieves
{
    boolean letterUsed = false;
    for(int x=0; x<used.length; x++)
    {
        if(alphabet == used[x])
        {
            letterUsed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            letterUsed = false;
        }
     }
     return letterUsed;
    for (int index = 0; index < used.length; index++)
    System.out.println(used[index]);
    //Or could i just do centreln(usedAlphabet)
}//End of usedLetters method
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
//checkWord method to see if the user has got the correct word
private void checkWord() throws IOException
{
    for(int x=0; x<currentWord.length; x++)
    {
        if(checkLetter.equals(currentWord))
        {
            centreln("HUZZAH! You have guessed the word!");
            centreln("You have completed this game of hangman.");
            menu();
        }

        {
            centreln("You have run out of guesses!");
            centreln("The word was:");
                for (int index = 0; index < currentWord.length; index++)
                {
                    System.out.print(currentWord[index]);
                }
            menu();
        }
    }
}//End of checkWord method
```

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

So I come up with this error:

```
C:\Users\HOME\Documents\twoHangman\src\twoHangman.java:272: error: '.class' expected
            checkWord(currentWord[] , checkLetter[]);
                                    ^
C:\Users\HOME\Documents\twoHangman\src\twoHangman.java:272: error: '.class' expected
            checkWord(currentWord[] , checkLetter[]);
                                                   ^
```

I am not sure what is wrong...Please help!

Comment: Did u save it as  *.java and then did u prepare .class file ?

Comment: How are you running the program? Java source files are generally compiled using a compiler (e.g. JDK) and then executed using a runtime environment (e.g. JRE).

Comment: @DRastislav, @McDowell: You can see clearly in the error message that the OP is trying to compile `twoHangman.java`

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem in in your `play()` method. Instead of

```
if (life == 0)
{
    checkWord(currentWord[] , checkLetter[]);
}
```

you should write

```
if (life == 0)
{
    checkWord(currentWord, checkLetter);
}
```

to pass the arrays as parameters.

As Kent pointed out, the other error is in your `checkWord` method. Instead of

```
private void checkWord() throws IOException
```

you should write

```
private void checkWord(char currentWord[], char checkLetter[]) throws IOException
```

to declare that this method takes two arguments of character array type.

Answer (score 1):

in your first code block, the play method, you have this method call:

```
checkWord(currentWord[] , checkLetter[]);
```

but take a look the method signature of checkWord():

```
private void checkWord() throws IOException
```

where are the parameters?

are your codes compiled?

Comment: I was taught that when you call a method, in the brackets, you name the variables that the method sends and in the method signature, you name the the variables the method receives...is this right

Comment: That is correct.  Your mistake is that you do not define the _parameters_ that the method receives in your method definition.  Also, `(` and `)` are called parentheses (not brackets).

Comment: I fixed the parameters that the methods pass and recieve, I compiled and came up with a few new errors. I need to get the user's input, then see if their input is in the word that they are guessing from, then I need to store what they have already guessed in an array and then display what they have not guessed as and underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method `checkWord` defined that does not take any arguments, however when you call that method you are passing 2 parameters `checkWord(currentWord[] , checkLetter[]);` you need to define a method that takes two params. Also when you are calling `checkWord(currentWord[], checkLetter[])` it should be `checkWord(currentWord, checkLetter)`

Edit to answer Question:
One way to solve your issue would be to update your definition of `checkWord` this way:

```
private void checkWord(String[] currentWord, String[] checkLetter) throws IOException
```

Comment: How do I define a method that takes two params?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I also noticed that when you initially try to call checkWord you are passing, what I think you intend to be an array, checkletter however when you are in checkWord you use checkletter as a string. You will want to change the definition to reflect whatever checkletter is supposed to be.